# Change Dart VM version

Tags: dart

I want to use the stable release of the sdk, which should be 2.2.0, but when I in the console check the version with the command "dart --version", it says I am running "Dart VM version: 2.1.0".

I have tried to upgrade via choco, and it says that I already have 2.2.0 installed.

Do I have multiple versions av Dart installed and can switch between them?

If so, can I set a default version?

Comment: When you run `dart`, you'll run whichever `dart` binary is found first in your search `PATH`.  You have multiple versions installed.  Uninstall the old version or modify `PATH` so that the location for 2.2.0 occurs first.

Comment: Ah, I'll check that out first thing in the morning!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just mark this as answered with the comment of jamsdlin, as it was the correct answer for me.

> When you run dart, you'll run whichever dart binary is found first in your search PATH. You have multiple versions installed. Uninstall the old version or modify PATH so that the location for 2.2.0 occurs first.